# Getting single color for Pandas barplot instead of colormap

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Having trouble understanding what is going on here. I am trying to provide the pandas barplot with a cmap, yet it comes out with only 1 color. This is in pandas version 0.22.0, please let me know if this can be recreated with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

a = pd.DataFrame({'count': {'2300-2399': 5273,
                            '3100-3399': 1384,
                            '4200-4299': 2662,
                            '4400-4599': 9454,
                            '4800-4999': 8145,
                            '5100-5199': 2719,
                            '5210-5239': 3187,
                            '5240-5249': 528}}
                )

a.plot(kind='bar', colormap='rainbow')
```

[image: pandas barplot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you coded it, all your bars belong to the same thing and are colored the same. Here's an example that'll give you something closer to what you need.

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

a = pd.DataFrame({'2300-2399': [ 5273 ],
                  '3100-3399': [ 1384 ],
                  '4200-4299': [ 2662 ],
                  '4400-4599': [ 9454 ],
                  '4800-4999': [ 8145 ],
                  '5100-5199': [ 2719 ],
                  '5210-5239': [ 3187 ],
                  '5240-5249': [ 528 ]}
                )

a.plot(kind='bar', colormap='rainbow')
```

[image]

Comment: `a.T.plot.bar(colormap='rainbow')` using OPs data set ;-)

Comment: Nice. That's a better answer :p

Comment: Thank you! This works but its a bit awkward to display categorical data in a continuous fashion, and I can't seem to figure out the xticks with more data (legend overload).

Comment: Pandas' `plot` function is actually a frontend for `matplotlib.pyplot`. I'm imagining you wanted spacing between the bars? Something like `plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))` to make the figure a bit bigger, and then `plt.bar(a['count'].keys(), a['count'], color=plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(a['count'].keys()))))` to do the actual plot?